# Find the perimeter and area of the quadrilateral IJKL

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

ABCD is a rectangle with sides 10 and 20. E,F,G and H are midpoints of their sides. Find the perimeter and area of IJKL.

[image]

So I was able to figure out the sides using similar triangles ($IJ = KL = 4\sqrt2$ and $IK=JL=2\sqrt{17}$, and thus the perimeter. I am unable to find the height of the parallelogram $IJKL$.

Comment: Please show the partial results you have obtained in the question body, **not in a comment.**

Comment: @rujuruki .. and delete old comments transferred to the question from comments area..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:*  Show that \begin{align}\operatorname{area} AJH+\operatorname{area}BFKI&=\operatorname{area} DKF+\operatorname{area}CHJL\\&=\operatorname{area}AEIJ+\operatorname{area}{CLG}\\&=\operatorname{area} DGLK+\operatorname{area}BIE=\operatorname{area}IKLJ.\end{align}
For the perimeter, show that $$2\overline{LG}=2\overline{EI}=\overline{AJ}=\overline{JL}=\overline{IK}=\overline{KD}.$$  Similarly, $$2\overline{JH}=2\overline{FK}=\overline{BI}=\overline{IJ}=\overline{CL}=\overline{LK}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of it this approach.